# Problems with updating or deleting rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go

I created the golang web api with postgresql `v11.01`. All works fine but some times I faced some problem with DB. When I try to delete or update some row in DB, DB going to Recovery mode and row that I tried to Update or delete is not affected. This problem is occurred randomly in random tables.

First time I thought that there some problems with my code, and I rewrote it with transactions but it is not helped me.
When I try to update row with DBForge, this app also hangs.

Also I thought that it was a problem with concurrency in golang, I also rewrote my code without concurrency. Did not help.

DB also configured to use multi-threading.

It is my endpoint controller for deletion:

```
var DeleteAntenna = func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
antenna_id := req.URL.Query().Get("antenna_id")
tx, err := database.DB.Begin()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    http.Error(res, err.Error(), 400)
    tx.Rollback()
    return
}

_, err = tx.Exec("UPDATE new_rollout_managment.cell SET antenna_id = NULL WHERE antenna_id = $1;", antenna_id)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    http.Error(res, err.Error(), 400)
    return
}

_, err = tx.Exec(`DELETE FROM "new_rollout_managment".antenna WHERE id = $1;`, antenna_id)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    http.Error(res, err.Error(), 400)
    tx.Rollback()
    return
}
defer tx.Commit()
resp := u.Message(true, "Deleted")
resp["Deleted_antenna"] = antenna_id

u.Respond(res, resp)
```

}

Please share any ideas

Comment: If the database goes into recovery, that means that the server has crashed. This is a bug and shouldn't happen. Look at the database log and [get a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend). Are you using any extensions? PostgreSQL cannot be configured to use multi-threading; what do you mean? Problems with PostgreSQL v12 should be reported to the pgsql-hackers mailing list, since it is in beta. Make sure you include the information I asked for here.

Comment: Thanks for quick answers. Excuse me for misleading you. There is Postgres 11.01.